# Chaining activities in robolectric tests

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric

I'm trying to push my tests in inter activity communications and check that for example after a correct login, I spawn the right activity (from 2 possibles activities).

Here's what my code looks like :

```
@RunWith(GuiceRobolectricJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {
@Inject
private LoginActivity activity;
@Inject
private ExplorerActivity startedActivity ;
@Inject
private Context context;

private Button loginButton;
private EditText login;
private EditText password;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity.onCreate(null);
    loginButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.identification_login_button);
    login = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
    password = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

}

@Online
@Test
public void shouldExploreWhenLoginIsCorrect() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(activity);
    login.setText("test@test.com");
    password.setText("test");
    activity.setIntent(new Intent());
    loginButton.performClick();
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(activity);
    Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);
    assertEquals(shadowIntent.getIntentClass(), ExplorerActivity.class);
//      startedActivity.setIntent(startedIntent);
//      startedActivity.onCreate(null);


    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't retrieve the started activity from the shadowintent. Is there a way I could achieve something like that? Also, I don't see anytrace of my exploreractivity and I was wondering if Robolectric was doing work to sandbox every spawning process. I would really love an example of chained activity tests in robolectric. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since it was 3 months ago, you may have already found your answer, if not, you can use `newInstance()` on what you already have, then continue onwards as per normal.

```
ExplorerActivity explorerActivity = (ExplorerActivity) shadowIntent.getIntentClass().newInstance();
explorerActivity.setIntent(startedIntent);
explorerActivity.onCreate(null);
```